# JAXB Partial unmarshalling of JSON

Tags: java, json, jaxb, unmarshalling

Consider the following JSON input:

```
{
    "url": [
        {
            "http://some_url": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "name1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Assume `http://some_url`is a valid url.This can be different in every response. All I am interested in is in the value of the property `http://some_url`. But since the key `http://some_url` can change, I am having difficulty creating a POJO for this. I just need to unmarshall the value of `http://some_url`. Is partial unmarshalling possible in this case? I have a `Details` class as my java class.

The bare-bones of `Details` class would be:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Details {
   @JsonProperty("id")
   public String id;
   @JsonProperty("name")
   public String name;
}
```

Since I am not sure how to do partial unmarshalling, I am doing:

```
Map<String,String> respData = null;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
respData = mapper.readValue({JSON STRING},Map.class);
```

Instead, what I would love somehow convert it to my `Details` class. I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: To Downvoter: Could you please add a reason why you downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Did manage to figure it out. Thanks to some late night coding, stackoverflow and some red-bull. I had to parse the JSON and used part of the JSONObject. The inspiration for this was a similar question but that person parsed XML instead.Refer: [Partial Unmarshalling of an XML using JAXB to skip some xmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656809/partial-unmarshalling-of-an-xml-using-jaxb-to-skip-some-xmlelement).  Following is the code if anyone is interested.

**POJO**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="dummy") // Does not work if I have no @XmlRootElement. Any suggestions?
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Details {
   @XmlElement(name = "id")
   public Double id;
   @XmlElement(name = "name")
   public String name;
}
```

**UNMARSHALING CLASS**

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getResponseBody()); // response.getResponseBody() returns a JSON string response from the API.
        JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("url");
        for(int i=0;i < array.length() ;i++) {
           JSONArray innerArray = array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(url); // url is the http://some_url
           JSONObject obj1 = innerArray.getJSONObject(0);


           JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
           // Needed to surround the JSONObject with a "dummy" property. Without this, my POJO class did not work. Is there a better way? 
           obj2.put("dummy",obj1);


           Configuration config = new Configuration();
           MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(config);
           XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj2, con);
           JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Details.class);
           Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
           Details detailsPOJO = (Details) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader);
           System.out.println("USER ID:"+detailsPOJO.id);
        }
```