# JAXB on-demand unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Say I have a very large XML file to unmarshal, like 2 MB. I don't want to unmarshal the file and end up with (aprox.) 2 MB of objects in memory.

Instead, I want to unmarshal portions of the file on-demand (i.e. as I navigate through the object structure) and cleanup the references of the objects I have already read, making them available to the garbage collector.

Is it possible to tweak the JAXB implementation in a way it unmarshals the XML on-demand instead of entirely at once?

Comment: Take a look in this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656809/partial-unmarshalling-of-an-xml-using-jaxb-to-skip-some-xmlelement

A specialist class was created to provide a mechanism to read the xml in parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in this solution: [Partial Unmarshalling of an XML using JAXB to skip some xmlElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656809/partial-unmarshalling-of-an-xml-using-jaxb-to-skip-some-xmlelement)

A specialist class was created to provide a mechanism to read the xml in parts.

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive example can be found [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html?m=1).

It uses StAX to advance to the right position within the xml file and JAXB to unmarshal the domain object.